# Equals width EditText?

Tags: android, layout

I have a screen that has textviews and edittexts.
I am trying to edittexts equal width. But they look very small width. I dont want to give a dip value. How can I do?
Thanks a lot.

```
 <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                >


                    <TableRow> 
                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name"
                        >
                    </TextView>
                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/name">
                    </EditText>
                    </TableRow>


                    <TableRow> 
                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Last Name"
                        >
                    </TextView>
                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/lastname">
                    </EditText>
                    </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: if possible then you should put what type of layout or view do you want and then mention what problems you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not wrap the following code in a Linearlayout, and add an attribute android:layout_weight=1 to both the TextView and EditText. This will help you to provide both of them of the same width!!

```
 <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name"
                    >
                </TextView>
                <EditText 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/name">
                </EditText>
```

Let me know if you have any queries

Comment: I put the android:layout_weight=1 line in editText and it worked. Thanks nithinreddy.

Comment: Cool! :) Mark as the right answer, so users who visit it later would know!

Answer (score 2):

You can give equal layout weight to text and edit view Like `android:layout_weight=".5"`

Answer (score 1):

The root of all problem is that you have given wrap content for all edit boxes. Since u have no default text or hint text, the size of it is set to minimum. Try adding a hint text or min width to get desired size boxes

Answer (score 0):

put this line for edit text in xml android:singleLine="true"